# how to export MySQL foreign keys only

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, save, export, dump

Does anyone know how to export, dump all foreign keys of a database ?
I want to modify fields and foreign keys are problematics, so i'd like to remove all foreign keys and to re-add them after my changes done.

Regards,
William

Answer (score 11):

**Be careful!**

Previously suggested solutions have some limitations. They don't work for multiple-column foreign keys and also crash when you have column or table named with some problematic word like `order` (which is quite common).

So I tried to fix them. This should be fully working SQL, it properly quotes tables and columns and supports multiple-column FKs:

**Deleting all FKs:**

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE `', kcu.TABLE_NAME, '` ',
    'DROP FOREIGN KEY `', kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, '`;'
)
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu
INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS rc ON
    kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
    kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
WHERE
    kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name_here' AND
    kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    kcu.TABLE_NAME,
    kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

**Adding all FKs:**

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    'ALTER TABLE ', fks.quotedSourceTableName, ' ',
    'ADD CONSTRAINT ', fks.quotedConstraintName, ' ',
    'FOREIGN KEY (', GROUP_CONCAT(fks.quotedSourceColumnName), ') ',
    'REFERENCES ', fks.quotedTargetTableName, ' (',
        GROUP_CONCAT(fks.quotedTargetColumnName),
    ') ',
    'ON DELETE ', fks.deleteRule, ' ',
    'ON UPDATE ', fks.updateRule, ';'
)
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONCAT('`', kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, '`') AS quotedConstraintName,
        CONCAT('`', kcu.TABLE_NAME, '`') AS quotedSourceTableName,
        CONCAT('`', kcu.COLUMN_NAME, '`') AS quotedSourceColumnName,
        CONCAT('`', kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, '`') AS quotedTargetTableName,
        CONCAT('`', kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, '`') AS quotedTargetColumnName,
        rc.DELETE_RULE AS deleteRule,
        rc.UPDATE_RULE AS updateRule
    FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu
    INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS rc ON
        kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
        kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    WHERE
        kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_database_name_here' AND
        kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY 
        kcu.ORDINAL_POSITION DESC
) AS fks
GROUP BY
    fks.quotedConstraintName,
    fks.quotedSourceTableName,
    fks.quotedTargetTableName,
    fks.deleteRule,
    fks.updateRule;
```

---

And just one last note: If you want to rename some columns, don't forget to rename them also in that SQLs for re-adding those foreign keys.

Answer (score 8):

Before:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

When you're done:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution,

- one SQL for save all FK :

  SELECT CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE ', tb1.TABLE_NAME, ' ADD CONSTRAINT ', tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME, ' FOREIGN KEY (', tb1.COLUMN_NAME, ') REFERENCES ', tb1.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, ' (', tb1.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, ') ON DELETE ',  tb2.DELETE_RULE, ' ON UPDATE ', tb2.UPDATE_RULE, ';')
  FROM information_schema.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS tb1
  INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS tb2 ON tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tb2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  WHERE table_schema = 'sfa' AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL
- and one SQL for delete all FK :

  SELECT CONCAT ('alter table ', tb1.TABLE_NAME,' drop foreign key ', tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';')
  FROM information_schema.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE` AS tb1
  INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS tb2 ON tb1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tb2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
  WHERE table_schema = 'sfa' AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL

I hope it could help someone ^^
William

Comment: That select is actually fawlty :)  
You need to join the two tables by the additional criteria of 
tb1.TABLE_SCHEMA=tb2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, otherwise you can join up multiple databases' fields.    Plus, all the back-ticks are missing; that can also cause trouble.   But the idea is good.

Comment: This will not support if a multi column index used as a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

```
select DISTINCT CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE `', kcu.TABLE_NAME, '` ADD CONSTRAINT `', kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, '` FOREIGN KEY (`', kcu.COLUMN_NAME, '`) REFERENCES `', kcu.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, '` (`', kcu.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME, '`) ON DELETE ', rc.DELETE_RULE, ' ON UPDATE ', rc.UPDATE_RULE, ';') FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS rc ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA WHERE table_schema = 'DB' AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL;


SELECT  DISTINCT CONCAT ('ALTER TABLE `', kcu.TABLE_NAME,'` DROP FOREIGN KEY `', kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME, '`;') FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS kcu INNER JOIN information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS rc ON kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME = rc.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = rc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA WHERE table_schema = 'DB' AND referenced_column_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Good answer but it always helps if you describe your answer in just a few words then just posting the coded solution. Besides that it would also help if you structure your answer somehow better.